# Error when removing an Object from the Queue

Tags: visual-workflow, deployment, queue

```
The Following queues are in use by default owner setting, workflow rule, sharing rule, email routing address or actual record owner: Deal_Approval
```

[image]

[image]

I found a suggestion [**here**](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A82zYSAR)

Based on this suggestion, it means , although I am trying to remove the Deal_Approval__c object from the Queue, I have to remove the field updates on other objects that are in the Queue. This is painful because, I have several queues, and each queue has more than 2 supported Objects selected. Also, each queue is referenced in several flows to assign records to that queue. Which means all other flows for other Objects will be affected.

The object I am trying to remove from queue is a redundant object that was created to test out a solution in the sandbox.

**I am thinking of following idea to deal with this dilemma and be able to deploy the flows -**

Create the Queues Manually in the higher environment, and deploy only the Flows that have the field updates that reference the Queue.

**Does anyone have a better solution?**